# Prepending Oracle SQL result with text

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query where I am checking whether the result is blank ('' rather than NULL) and if it is not then I want to prepend the result with some text.

Here's the query...

```
SELECT *, 
CASE my_col 
WHEN '' 
THEN '' 
ELSE 'Blah blah ' + my_col 
END AS my_col2 
FROM table_name
```

The error I am getting back looks like this...

`ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Simple solution I'm sure, but any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oracle an empty string is null, so the condition `WHEN ''` will never be true. You need to check for `NULL`

```
SELECT table_name.*, 
       CASE 
         WHEN my_col IS NULL THEN '' 
         ELSE 'Blah blah ' || my_col 
      END AS my_col2 
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 3):

concat string - `||`

in oracle world `'' is null` = true

Answer (score 0):

`+` won't work in Oracle. Use ||. Also try listing out all columns intead of *

```
SELECT *,  
CASE my_col  
WHEN ''  
THEN ''  
ELSE 'Blah blah ' || my_col  
END AS my_col2  
FROM table_name
```